# How to upload my application in App Hub

Tags: windows-phone-7

I can't upload my application in App Hub,When i submit a application then it shows an error message "Error occurred connection to server"
Please you help me !
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The AppHub is Silverlight based, try cleaning up your cache of your browser and try again. This solved my problem.

Comment: Thank invalidusername ! when i upload my application in App Hub , erros :"this application name is already exit" ?

Comment: seems like you already successfully uploaded your app. Upload a screenshot so we can better help you.